# move backwards when iterate a for in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

imagine this situation:

a file with 1000 lines. the name of the file is file.txt

```
file = file.txt
word = 'error'
for line in file:
    if word in line:
        execute things
```

if I want the 8 lines BEFORE the line with the word "error", how I get it?

Comment: What happens if the *word* is found in line 4?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein

The output in file is a group of 9 lines. if error apears, is in the last line.

Comment: A file with 1000 lines cannot be divided into groups of 9 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file and save the lines in a `deque` of a fixed size

```
from collections import deque

file = "file.txt"
word = 'error'

lines = deque(maxlen=8)
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            break
        lines.append(line)

print(lines)
```

Comment: I think that the op wants `lines[-9:-1]`, that's 8 lines before the 'error' line.

Comment: What about `deque` with `maxlen`? `lines = deque(maxlen=8)` and no additional action needed.

Comment: Even better if add `takewhile()`: `deque(takewhile(lambda x: word not in line, file), maxlen=8)`

Comment: It should be `lambda line: word not in line` or `lambda x: word not in x`, sorry for typo.

Comment: Using `collections.deque` is the way to go here to maintain a fixed-size buffer efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [`collections.deque()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with fixed length and [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import takewhile

with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = deque(takewhile(lambda l: "error" not in l, f), maxlen=8)
print(*lines, sep="", end="")
```